# Forward all Chatter Comms to mail account

Tags: chatter

We monitor all our Email Communications, and we are thinking of starting to use chatter. We would need to send all Chatter communications to one single mail account, where our rules are then applied to all communications. Is that possible at all?

Tia.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Microsoft Outlook, you may want to try to create a rule.